# Google Chrome will not launch (Windows 10)

Tags: windows, google-chrome, windows-10, browser

I have a HP ENVY running Windows 10. For some reason, the PC is unable to launch Google Chrome. When I launch the Task Manager, I see multiple Google Chrome processes running, however there is no active Google Chrome browser that I am able to see or interact with. I have tried:

1. Restart PC
2. Uninstall/Reinstall Chrome
3. Disable firewall/antivirus
4. Alt+Windows to see if it is on a different screen
5. Other browsers work just fine.

I have also done a lot of research in other forums about why Google Chrome will not launch, and have not found a solution.

Comment: Has Chrome ever worked on your computer? If it's just recently stopped working, you could try using the [Chrome Repair Tool](https://www.google.com/chrome/cleanup-tool/) provided by Google.

Comment: Are you trying to launch the 32-bit or 64-bit Chrome client?

Comment: I am running 32-bit chrome, however, my laptop is 64 bit. @ Ramhound

Comment: Chrome has always had issues with this laptop from day one. It opens sometimes and will remain open and work fine. It is when you close chrome that opening it becomes an issue. @int_541

Comment: UPDATE:
I followed the video at this link https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gUnNS7NbCn0
and was able to successfully clear all Google Data from the machine. I even used the registry cleaner until it would no longer find an issue (cleaner discussed in video). 
From here, I notice that the disk usage was hovering around 100% and thus did some googling. I came across this link
http://www.tomshardware.com/forum/id-2813275/disk-usage-100.html
Which helped me address that issue. Now, Chrome appears to be functioning properly and launches each time. I am running the 32 bit version FYI. Thanks for help!

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, uninstall Chrome, then create a new user with administrative rights. Install Chrome again, but this time try using http://ninite.com/ - Once installed, open, test for any website.

Logout, and back into the profile where it doesn't work. Search for the Chrome executable and run again.

If still no joy then you will have to create a new profile for yourself and move everything (apart from the registry) over.

Comment: What is the purpose of ninite exactly?

Comment: @Ramhound Ninite is used to install multiple applications at once with as few clicks as possible. In addition, it will avoid installing any tool-bars or other "extras" that come with programs when you download them from other websites. On top of all that, the same executable you download the first time can be ran again and again to update the apps you originally selected.

Comment: I have had issues with the standard Chrome installer in the past, so now I just use Ninite.

Comment: What will doing this achieve for me?

Comment: The Standard Chrome installer sometimes does not work - The site ninite packages apps up in it's own specific way. Useful when installers are giving problems

Answer (score -1):

Your Chrome profile is usually left behind after uninstalling and reinstalling. If after reinstalling the browser you find you still have the problem, then the issue is likely with the user profile for that browser, in this case Chrome. I recommend doing the following to be sure it is fully reinstalled, with a fresh default user profile:

1. Uninstall Chrome as before.
2. Make sure Chrome is no longer located at 
   `C:\Program files (x86)\Google Chrome`
3. Enable hidden folders in Windows Explorer:

   https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4028316/windows-view-hidden-files-and-folders-in-windows-10
4. Open Windows Explorer (File Explorer), and go to the following folder:

   `C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\`
5. Rename **User Data** to **User Data.old**
6. Restart your computer
7. Reinstall Chrome, using the offline installer (to make the install faster):

   https://www.google.com/intl/en/chrome/?standalone=1

Let us know if this works better for you. Hope everything gets working soon.